# ASPNET MVC3 Generics with Controllers and Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've been trying to come up with an extensible search pattern for an mvc site I'm working on and I wanted some base functionality to minimize what I need to do to extend the search by adding another controller option.

I'm having a problem determining where I would go from having a base abstract searchable controller that presumes a particular entity and model type.  The **Mapper** reference refers to AutoMapper and just maps the entity to the model.  Everything seems to work ok but I'm not sure what the view would look like in terms of the model definition because the type is variable for the base model SearchModel.  I could implement my own view in each controller with the @model SearchModel but I'm just wondering how much "free" plumbing I can get away with.

```
public abstract class SearchableController<TModel, TEntity, TRepository> : Controller where TRepository : ISearchableRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class where TModel : class
{
    protected TRepository _repository;

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Search(string q, int? page)
    {
        int pageNumber = page.HasValue ? page.Value : 1;
        PagedList<TEntity> entities = _repository.Search(q, 10, page);

        Mapper.CreateMap<TEntity, TModel>();
        var results = new List<TModel>();
        foreach (TEntity entity in entities)
        {
            var entityModel = Mapper.Map<TEntity, TModel>(entity);
            results.Add(entityModel);
        }

        var model = new SearchModel<TModel>();
        model.searchPattern = q;
        model.pageNumber = pageNumber;
        model.Results = new StaticPagedList<TModel>(results, entities.PageNumber, entities.PageSize, entities.TotalItemCount);

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I don't really understand your problem.

Your model would be an `@model SearchModel<WhateverYourTModelIs>`.  What "free plumbing" are you referring to?

Maybe i'm confused, but you have to define the static types for your derived controllers, so what is your problem with defining static type views for them?

Comment: Much of what happens in the search result view is just pagination, search box and enumerating over the result set which would be something the concrete implementation might have a partial view for so that it could have a specific item format (i.e. person vs. book might look different, including any actions that you might be able to perform on the individual item).  The implemented controllers can just use a master view that facilitates that as well I guess based on a SearchModel<Object> or something I suppose.

Comment: @Lawrence - I'm not sure I'm understanding your point.  You must make concrete versions of you controllers.  ie `public class MyController : SearchableController<SomeModel, SomeEntity, SomeRepository)`, so since you have to do that, what is the problem with using `@model SearchModel<SomeModel>`?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I think that is the route I ended up with.  Then I just use a master view that handles the common view portion of the search model like the search pattern rebind to a search input, pagination, current page number etc...